# Can Twice copy One for All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Monoma who has the quirk copy, it's said he can't copy One for All (or at least, he can't copy it effectively) What about Twice? Can he copy Midoriya along with his powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, based on the description in the [wiki](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Double), which is also from the manga, the quirk of Twice can copy *any person along with its abilities, albeit it would be weaker and less powerful than the original*.

If I recall correctly, Midoriya has not yet been copied by Twice so *we have no way to find out if there is an exception to his ability*, like with Monoma.